# Image Base64 not getting Sent Correctly in JSON Request

Tags: php, ios, xcode, json, base64

I am sending an image in base64 in JSON POST request to php server. Response comes Ok. But spaces are getting added to the base64 string. So when I try to decode the base64, it fails. Could not understand where the problem is. I am working on an iPad app and sending the request from iPad simulator.

Let me know if you even have slightest idea of what could be wrong. Thanks much.

Following is the ASIRequest code I am using for sending the request -

```
ASIFormDataRequest *asiRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlForAPI]];
[asiRequest setTimeOutSeconds:200];

NSMutableDictionary *requestheaders =[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init] autorelease];
[requestheaders setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forKey:@"Content-Type"];

NSData *jsonData = [data JSONData];

NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
[asiRequest setRequestHeaders:requestheaders];
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"REQUEST=%@",string];

NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonString UTF8String] length:[jsonString length]];

[asiRequest setPostBody:[NSMutableData dataWithData:requestData]];

[asiRequest setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[asiRequest setDelegate:self];

[asiRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[asiRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
[asiRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];

[asiRequest startSynchronous];
```

Comment: Can we see an example of the post request and what the server is receiving? `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD I have updated the question with the code. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

try this

it declare on top:

```
   static const char _base64EncodingTable[64] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    /Write this code when you pass the string.
         NSData *imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(YourImageView.image);
         NSString *imageString = [self encodeBase64WithData:imageData];

  //  only pass this imageStirng using NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of UTF8String
```

no other parameter just check image is uploaded or not. its work for me.

```
   YourUrl= [[YourUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]



    - (NSString *)encodeBase64WithData:(NSData *)objData {
        const unsigned char * objRawData = [objData bytes];
        char * objPointer;
        char * strResult;

        // Get the Raw Data length and ensure we actually have data
        int intLength = [objData length];
        if (intLength == 0) return nil;

        // Setup the String-based Result placeholder and pointer within that placeholder
        strResult = (char *)calloc((((intLength + 2) / 3) * 4) + 1, sizeof(char));
        objPointer = strResult;

        // Iterate through everything
        while (intLength > 2) { // keep going until we have less than 24 bits
            *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[objRawData[0] >> 2];
            *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[((objRawData[0] & 0x03) << 4) + (objRawData[1] >> 4)];
            *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[((objRawData[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + (objRawData[2] >> 6)];
            *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[objRawData[2] & 0x3f];

            // we just handled 3 octets (24 bits) of data
            objRawData += 3;
            intLength -= 3;
        }

        // now deal with the tail end of things
        if (intLength != 0) {
            *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[objRawData[0] >> 2];
            if (intLength > 1) {
                *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[((objRawData[0] & 0x03) << 4) + (objRawData[1] >> 4)];
                *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[(objRawData[1] & 0x0f) << 2];
                *objPointer++ = '=';
            } else {
                *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[(objRawData[0] & 0x03) << 4];
                *objPointer++ = '=';
                *objPointer++ = '=';
            }
        }

        // Terminate the string-based result
        *objPointer = '\0';

        // Return the results as an NSString object
        return [NSString stringWithCString:strResult encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    }
```

it may help you. and also it's possible there is problem with getting image on server.